# javascript visual studio making an object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to just simply make an object in javascript via visual studio. My syntax inside my function that is getting called is simply:

```
var d = new Object();
d.id = 8;
```

When I launch my page from Visual Studio and click my button that fires the function that has those 2 lines of code in it, I get an error at d.id where it's showing d as undefined still. I just want a generic object that I can assign properties to. What am I missing?

There isn't much more code to show. The total function as of right now:

```
function btnTest_onClick() {

    var d = new Object();
    d.id = 8;
}
```

In my default.aspx I have 
I removed the tags because stackoverflow doesn't seem to like them

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="btnTest_onClick()" />
```

I'm just trying to learn this stuff so I'm starting very basic and small. This doesn't really make sense to me. The function gets called just fine.

Exact error is:
    JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'id' of undefined or null reference

The entire HTML Page. This is literally Project->New Website, and add a button.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"     AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Process.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.</p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="btnTest_onClick()" /></p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you show more code .. As how and where you are calling your function ??

Comment: Where are you getting the value of `d.id` from? Are you alerting it? Using `console.log`?

Comment: Literally hardcoding it just for testing. It's 8 like shown above just for testing.

Comment: Are you enclosing your function inside script tags.. Can you copy the whole code..

Comment: There's no error here, are you sure this is **all** of the relevant code?

Comment: My function is in a separate file which on the aspx page I include. The function gets called just fine. I can step into it. @tjameson this literally is all the code. I'm just learning about javascript (program in many other languages) so I'm starting small.

Comment: I have Win 8, using Visual Web Developer 2010 express btw. The strange thing is in another test I'm making ajax calls to a WebMethod and that works just fine when using the shorthand object creation.

Comment: Can you show the whole HTML structure of your document.. Maybe that should help ..

Comment: It's very basic. All I did was a new website, then added 1 button.